# Dropbox and the Mac App Store

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Can a Mac App Store app store files in dropbox from within the OS X sandbox?

I am not able find out wether the dropbox SDK allows access to a users folder while in the sandbox.

Comment: I think your application just needs to have the correct entitlements, in the case of Dropbox SDK I'd imagine you need to allow outgoing network connections (to connect to Dropbox) and allow access to one of the the user's file locations (and/or user-specified files).